# Lazy load @DBRef field with spring data

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Using Spring Data with mondoDb. I have a user POJO with some fields annotated as `@DBRef(lazy = true)`. With certain queries I would like to populate these fields with their data. I can't figure out how.

Lets say I have users collection and organizations collection. `User` POJO has a field

```
@DBRef(lazy = true)
private Organization org;
```

I then execute

```
List<User> user = mongoTemplate.find(userQuery, User.class);
```

At this point I do see the `user.get(0).getOrg()` returning an object of type `Organization`, with only id field populated.

Here I would like to specify somewhere that I would like all org fields to be populated with their data (similar to how mongooseJS allows you to configure a query to populate certain fields)